# Должна ли быть запятая между однородными членами предложения? при условии наличия союзов либо либо

Tags: пунктуация

К нам на работу могут попасть либо очень талантливые либо очень умные люди

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, должна. Конструкция "либо то, либо это" всегда разделяется запятой.

Answer (score 2):

Сочинительные союзы И, ИЛИ, ЛИБО и другие бывают повторяющимися, когда используются при однородных членах. В этом случае между однородными членами ставится запятая: *либо талантливые, либо очень умные.*